How to show modified files in IntelliJ IDEA similar to Eclipse > indicator?
I'm transitioning from Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA and I'm trying to find a feature that I found very useful in Eclipse.
In Eclipse, whenever I make a change to a file, a '>' symbol is added at the beginning of the file in the project tree.
This makes it easy to see which files have been modified.
I'm looking for a similar feature in IntelliJ IDEA.
I understand that IntelliJ uses color coding to indicate the status of files, but I'm specifically interested in a symbol or indicator similar to the '>' in Eclipse that would appear in the project tree.
Does IntelliJ IDEA have a feature like this?
If not, is there a plugin or configuration that can add this functionality?
Eclipse:

IntelliJ:

As you can see, on Eclipse is very easy to see when there are uncommitted changes.
It shows an > to the project, the maven module, folder, package, .java file

Nope, no such feature in IDEA out of the box. Color coding works really well along with the "All Changed Files" view mode of the Project tool window that shows only modified files. You can also try your hand at developing your own plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/developing-plugins.html
